# Conflict between tikz and tableofcontents

Tags: bibliographies, document-classes, incompatibility

To submit my paper, I need to use the Springer document class (link below). It turns out that it creates a conflict between Tikz and '\tableofcontents' which causes the compiler to **not** create a bibliography (go figure). If I remove either the Tikz declarations, and/or the table of contents command, the bibliography runs just dandy. I spent a while trying to understand where the conflict lies, but it is beyond me.

I stripped my file to the bare minimum, and added a sample bib file. Unfortunately, the class files are too long to post here directly, but [here is the link](https://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/468198/application/zip/LaTeX_DL_468198_240419.zip) from Springer's webpage (only the svjour3.cls and svglov3.clo files are needed).

main.tex:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
%%% Springer class for Math Z

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,calc}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\title{Bibliography trouble}
\author{GI Joe}

\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\tableofcontents{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section{One section is enough for trouble}

{\large
The Springer document class creates a clash between Tikz and Table of Contents. \\

No bibliography entry is created for~\cite{A} or~\cite{B}. But if you comment the tikz package declarations (lines 5--7), {\bf OR} if you comment the table of contents command (line 20), the bibliography runs just fine.} \\

\begin{center}{\Large WHY!?}\end{center}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

bibliography.bib:

```
@article {A,
AUTHOR = {Arthur Ashe},
TITLE = {An able acorn},
JOURNAL = {Antarctica J.},
VOLUME = {1},
YEAR = {1901},
NUMBER = {1},
PAGES = {1--2}
}


@incollection {B,
AUTHOR = "Barry Bonds",
TITLE = "Bibliography blunders",
BOOKTITLE = "Bibliography Book",
PAGES = "1--100",
PUBLISHER = "Basic Books",
YEAR = "1901"
}
```

Comment: Add `\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}` before \end{document}. This is only a work-around, I need to think about it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the class tries to write at end document to the toc an `\endgroup`:

```
 \AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
```

but tikz issues a `\clearpage` first, and then the write is never executed.

As a work around you can add this to the preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*\protected@iwrite[3]{%
  \begingroup
  \let\thepage\relax
  #2%
  \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
  \edef\reserved@a{\immediate\write#1{#3}}\reserved@a
  \endgroup
  \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}
\AtEndDocument{\let\protected@write\protected@iwrite}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
```

An alternative with a current latex is to redefine \tableofcontents to use another hook:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\small}%
    \AddToHook{shipout/lastpage}{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
    }

\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the use of `\AtEndDocumet` in the svjour3.cls. This code is used for set to small the font size of the contents. A possible workaround is just comment the are problematic lines in svjour3.cls,

```
1152c1152
<     %\section*{\contentsname}%
---
>     \section*{\contentsname}%
1154,1155c1154,1155
<     %\addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\small}%
<     %\AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
---
>     \addtocontents{toc}{\begingroup\protect\small}%
>     \AtEndDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}}%
```

and set the font size of contents in the main document:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section*{\contentsname}%
{\small
\tableofcontents{}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Original,

[image]

and with the workaround

[image]